# How to make an end ellipses to the middle TextView

Tags: android

I want to make an end ellipsized to  text, views like following

"First-TextView Second-Te... Third-TextView"

I tried like following, but if there is not enough space, a third TextView can not be shown

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second TextView"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Third TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: share image that excellently you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="First TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="Second TextView"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Third TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but, it makes spaces between first and second, I need left align all 3 textviews

Comment: just write android:gravity="left" to each textView

Comment: means, you want your text will be left alligned right?

Comment: There is no any space at all, as I have checked it out.

Comment: I tested out, it's not working. I think he wanted first text and second text to have no space between.